# FuelPHP: Cascading Delete Not Working

Tags: php, fuelphp

I have two tables. One is category and that category has MANY nominations.

Table Category

```
protected static $_has_many = array(
        'nominations' => array(
            'key_from' => 'id',
            'key_to'   => 'category_id',
            'model_to' => 'Model_Nominations',
            'cascade_save'  => true,
            'cascade_delete'=> true
        )
);
```

Table Nominations

```
protected static $_belongs_to = array(
        'categories' => array(
            'key_from'      => 'category_id',
            'key_to'        => 'id',
            'model_to'      => 'Model_Categories',
            'cascade_save'  => true,
            'cascade_delete'=> true
        )
);
```

When I delete the categories:

```
public static function delete_($args)
{
        $q = Model_Categories::query()
                ->where('id','=',$args['id']);
        if($q->count() > 0){
            $q->delete();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
}
```

It doesn't delete the nomination entries in the Nominations table even with the `cascade_delete` set to true. What did I miss?

Comment: Which Fuel version? Have you enabled the profiler to check the queries that were generated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your logic is wrong.

In your example `$q` is an ORM query object, so that delete just runs a delete query: `DELETE FROM categories WHERE id = ?`.

You need to fetch a model object with it's relations if you want to delete an object and it's relations. It will not cascade into relations that are not loaded.

```
public static function delete_($args)
{
    if ($result = Model_Categories::find($args['id'], array('related'=>array('nominations')))
    {
        return $result->delete();
    }
    return false;
}
```